# Android: animated textview

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

In reference to this question:
[Android, make an animation text scroll up on the screen like first part of Star Wars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289565/android-make-an-animation-text-scroll-up-on-the-screen-like-first-part-of-star)

I'm loading a large string into the textview and the bottom is being taken off as the animation moves the textview up the screen. This appears to be because the textview element can only be as large as the parent RelativeLayout.

I've tried assigning a large (2000dp) layout_height to the textview to no avail.

Is there a way to make the textview item larger than the Relative Layout that it resides so that this clipping will not occur and the entire string can be displayed?